# Rshiny Highchart: keeping fixed color for order-changing categories on x axis

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

Good afternoon All,

I am working on a bar chart in Rshiny. On the X axis, I have 3 months displayed. Their order may change depending on the user's input. I would like to keep the same color for each month, whatever is its position on the x axis: for example, I want "Jan" series to be in blue, no matter if it is located 3rd or 1st on the X axis. I provide below a simplified sample of the code:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
               highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
        ),
        selectInput("option", label = "",  width = "100%",
                    choices = c("Tokyo", "NY"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- citytemp[,c("month","tokyo","new_york")]
    data = data[data$month%in%c("Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar"),]
    choose_Option <- reactive({
        sort_option <- input$option
        if(sort_option=="Tokyo"){
            data = data[order(data$tokyo),]
        }
        else{
            data = data[order(data$new_york),]
        }
        return(data)
    })
    output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
        data = choose_Option()
        data = data[1:3,] 
        colors_for_categories <- c()

        colors_fun <- function(month){
            if(month=="Dec"){return (c("#1B1858"))}
            if(month=="Jan"){return (c("#00A1DE"))}
            if(month=="Feb"){return (c("#2E28AB"))}
            if(month=="Mar"){return (c("#0D653C"))} 
        }

        colors_for_categories  <- colors_fun(data$month[[1]])
        for(m in 2:3){
            colors_for_categories  <- append(colors_for_categories ,colors_fun(data$month[[m]]))
        }
        chart <-  highchart() %>% 
            hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
            hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature for main cities") %>% 
            hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
            hc_xAxis(categories = data$month) %>% 
            hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)")) 

        hc <- chart %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="Tokyo",data = data$tokyo,colorByPoint=TRUE,colors=colors_for_categories )
        hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="NY",data = data$new_york,colorByPoint=TRUE,colors=colors_for_categories )    

        return(hc)
    })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can see that you can select Tokyo or NY in the options below the chart. Depending on your choice, Feb and Jan do not have the same position on the X axis but the related series have always the same color.
The solution I implemented is very limited: it consists in determining the new position of each month (each time the input changes!) and then in allocating the right color. But this needs to work for a large amount of data, and I think it is not the best approach. Do you have an idea / suggestion about handling this problem ?
Thank you very much for your help !
Best, Madzia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ! The method may be to create a table that has all the colors & months. 
The same table is used for each chart, and therefore we can easily create colors_for_categories above.
Please let me know if you have questions about it.

Best, Madzia